# При добавлении нового товара в local storage в какой-то момент начинают дублироваться значения

Tags: javascript, json, localstorage

Скрипт получает id кнопки и по нему находит нужные мне данные из html.
Далее он проверяет есть ли запись в LS, если нет, то втупую заносит туда первую запись.
Если же записи есть, то я получаю каждый товар поочередно и проверяю id нового товара, с уже существующими в LS. Если сходство есть - я меняю кол-во нужных пользователю товаров на новое значение и возвращаю в LS.

```
/*Добавить товары в корзину*/
function addToCart(x){
    let cart = [];
    /*находим id продукта*/
    let id = x.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    /*зная id продукта, узнаем кол-во нужных клиенту товаров*/
    let count = document.getElementById("amountInput" + id).value;/*кол-во товаров*/
    /*Узнаем цену за единицу продукта*/
    let price = document.getElementById("product-price" + id).innerHTML;
    /*Находим фотку товара*/
    let photo = document.getElementById("product-img" + id).getAttribute("src");
    /*Узнаем название товара*/
    let name = document.getElementById("product-name" + id).innerHTML;
    /*Если в корзине пока ничего нет*/
    if(!localStorage.getItem("products")){
        cart.push({"id":id, "name":name, "count":count, "price":price, "photo":photo});
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
    /*Если в корзине уже есть товары, проверяем на сходство*/
    else{
        let bask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
        for(i=0; i<bask.length; i++){
            if(bask[i].id==id){
                bask[i].count = count;
                localStorage.setItem("products",JSON.stringify(bask));
            }else{
                let prod = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
                prod.push({"id":id,"name":name, "count":count, "price":price, "photo":photo});
                localStorage.setItem("products",JSON.stringify(prod));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что первый и второй товар в LS добавляются нормально, но третий дублируется, а четвертый добавляется 4 раза. В чем моя ошибка? Помогите пожалуйста(уже 15 часов за кодом и мозги не варят).
Вот так выглядит LS, когда я добавил всего 4 товара:

```
0
: 
{id: "1", name: "Удон с телятиной", count: "1", price: "179", photo: "Photos/Udon-san.png"}
1
: 
{id: "2", name: "Боул с креветками", count: "1", price: "249", photo: "Photos/Bowl-with-shrimps.png"}
2
: 
{id: "3", name: "Ролл Филадельфия", count: "1", price: "249", photo: "Photos/Philadelphi-classic.png"}
3
: 
{id: "3", name: "Ролл Филадельфия", count: "1", price: "249", photo: "Photos/Philadelphi-classic.png"}
4
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
5
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
6
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
7
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте пройдемся по вашему коду:

```
        for(i=0; i<bask.length; i++){
            if(bask[i].id==id){
                bask[i].count = count;
                localStorage.setItem("products",JSON.stringify(bask));
            }else{
                let prod = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
                prod.push({"id":id,"name":name, "count":count, "price":price, "photo":photo});
                localStorage.setItem("products",JSON.stringify(prod));
            }
        }
```

Этот участок работает не так, как вы описываете. Представим, что к тому выводу, что вы приложили в вопросе, мы решим добавить еще один товар с `id == 4`, например. Этот кусок кода будет перебирать все позиции из LS, независимо от наличия элемента с нужным id. Если он встретит таковой, он отработает по вашему условию `bask[i].id==id`, а если нет -- будет выполняться блок `else`. Т.е. при длине корзины в 7 элементов, где уже есть 4 элемента с `id == 4`, до встречи такового интерпретатор отработает по `else`, добавляя новые элементы с `id == 4`, а потом с оставшимися будет работать по условию в `if`. Причем благодаря строчке `bask[i].count = count;` у вас будет перезаписываться количество элементов, а не плюсоваться. А на выходе получится примерно такая картина:

```
0
: 
{id: "1", name: "Удон с телятиной", count: "1", price: "179", photo: "Photos/Udon-san.png"}
1
: 
{id: "2", name: "Боул с креветками", count: "1", price: "249", photo: "Photos/Bowl-with-shrimps.png"}
2
: 
{id: "3", name: "Ролл Филадельфия", count: "1", price: "249", photo: "Photos/Philadelphi-classic.png"}
3
: 
{id: "3", name: "Ролл Филадельфия", count: "1", price: "249", photo: "Photos/Philadelphi-classic.png"}
4
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
5
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
6
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
7
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
8
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
9
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
10
: 
{id: "4", name: "Греческий салат", count: "1", price: "149", photo: "Photos/Greek-salad.png"}
```

Решение примерно такое:

```
/*Добавить товары в корзину*/
function addToCart(x){
    let cart = [];
    /*находим id продукта*/
    let id = x.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
    /*зная id продукта, узнаем кол-во нужных клиенту товаров*/
    let count = document.getElementById("amountInput" + id).value;/*кол-во товаров*/
    /*Узнаем цену за единицу продукта*/
    let price = document.getElementById("product-price" + id).innerHTML;
    /*Находим фотку товара*/
    let photo = document.getElementById("product-img" + id).getAttribute("src");
    /*Узнаем название товара*/
    let name = document.getElementById("product-name" + id).innerHTML;
    /*Если в корзине пока ничего нет*/
    if(!localStorage.getItem("products")){
        cart.push({"id":id, "name":name, "count":count, "price":price, "photo":photo});
        localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }
    /*Если в корзине уже есть товары, проверяем на сходство*/
    else{
       let bask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products")); // парсим products из LS
       let elem = bask.find(item => item.id == id);             // используем метод find для поиска нужного элемента, вернет либо элемент, если он найден, либо undefined
       if (elem) elem.count += count;                           // если найден, то плюсуем count
       else bask.push({"id":id,"name":name, "count":count, "price":price, "photo":photo}); // если не найден, то добавляем в корзину. 
       localStorage.setItem("products",JSON.stringify(bask)); // переводим json обратно в строку и убираем в LS
    }
}
```

Comment: Ты просто боженька!!! Спасибо огромное)))
PS для тех кто когда-то столкнется с такой же проблемой - `if (elem) elem.count += count;` замените на `elem.count = Number(elem.count)+Number(count);` , иначе у вас строки будут складываться. На этом все. Пара-Пара-ПАМ!